# When I try to "Enable-Migration" in dataLayer in mvc5 project I get this error. How can I fix it.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, entity-framework-migrations, nuget-package-restore

Migration can be enabled in the main project but I receive error in data layer part.

Here it is :

```
PM> enable-migrations
```

> Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///F:\MVC-Projects\testWebApplication1\pack
> ages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> specified."
>
> At F:\MVC-Projects\testWebApplication1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:62
>
> - $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll))
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>
> At F:\MVC-Projects\testWebApplication1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:50
>
> - $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///F:\MVC-Projects\testWebApplica
> tion1\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
>
> At F:\MVC-Projects\testWebApplication1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:31
>
> - $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I used these commands in the Nuget console:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.2
Enable-Migrations
```